# How to obtain 2 sets of key,value pair in each iteration of for-loop?

Tags: python

I know I can use this to print key/value pair in each iteration.
Can I obtain two sets of key/value pair in single iteration?

```
for key,value in dict1.items():
   print(key + "\t" + value)
```

Comment: Can you show an example input and expected output?

Comment: Do the two dicts have the same size? I recommend using zip if that's the case (if not, you'll only get the shorter of the two.)

Comment: Look for the `grouper` function in the [`itertools` recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

Comment: Can you guarantee that the dict will always have an even number of keys? If not, what do you want to happy when you get to the end and only have 1 key/value pair left?

Answer (score 2):

Yea, put your keys in a list, then unlock dictionary values with that.  `iter()` does well for this, because it has `.next()`.  Just make sure your dict has an even number of entries, or do one final `next(keys)` if it's odd.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
dict1 = { 'this':0, 'that':1, 'and':2, 'the':3, 'other':4, 'thing':5 }

keys = iter( dict1 .keys() )

for i in range( len( dict1 ) //2 ):
    key1 = next( keys )
    value1 = dict1[ key1 ]
    print( f'{key1}    {value1}' )

    key2 = next( keys )
    value2 = dict1[ key2 ]
    print( f'{key2}    {value2}' )

    print()
```

> this    0
> that    1
>
> and    2
> the    3
>
> other    4
> thing    5

Comment: It works for me. Thanks very much. I will try other solutions provided below later.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`itertools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
from itertools import zip_longest


def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

The `fillvalue` argument lets you specify what to produce if your iterator has an odd length.

```
dict1 = dict(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4, e=5)
for (key1,value1), (key2, value2) in grouper(dict1.items(), 2, ("-", "-")):
   print(key1, value1, sep="\t")
   print(key2, value2, sep="\t")
   print("===")
```

The output is

```
a        1
b        2
===
c        3
d        4
===
e        5
-        -
===
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by simple loop, but in case it has odd number of keys in dict then in the last iteration you will get only one key-pair value.

```
dict = {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"}
dict_keys = list(dict.keys())
for index in range(0, round(len(dict_keys)/2) + 1, 2):
    print("First Key Value Pair : ")
    print(dict_keys[index], dict[dict_keys[index]]
    
    if (index + 1) < len(dict_keys):
        print("Second Key Value Pair : ")
        print(dict_keys[index + 1], dict[dict_keys[index + 1]])
```